# Передача данных в TextBox при парсинге AngleSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, anglesharp

Использую для парсинга библиотеку AngleSharp. После парсинга не могу вывести данные в TextBox. При клике на кнопку должна проиходить операция скачивания страницы и поиска в ней по Linq данных по заданным критериям. Прошу указать на ошибку, кто использует WPF. Заранее спасибо.

```
    private void BtnCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parser = new HtmlParser();
        var document = parser.ParseDocument(Convert.ToString(TextBoxFind));
        var result = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "img" && m.ClassList.Contains("post__image-link"));
        string res = "";
        foreach (var b in result)
        {
            res += b;
        }
        TextBoxContent.Text = res;}
```

Comment: А что не так?..

Comment: @Bulson TextBox остается пустой

Comment: Не могу распарсить? (вопрос о англшарпе) Или не могу вставить? (не умею работать с wpf)

Comment: `TextBox.Content = res`

Comment: @A K скорее не умею работать с WPF

Comment: То есть у вас есть строка `var res = "asdf";` и вам нужно её показать в textbox'е и anglesharp ни при чём? Если так - сузьте вопрос, вырезав всё не относящееся к делу. Если anglesharp парсит всё правильно - не надо лишний код в вопрос пихать.

Comment: Поставить брейкпойнт и посмотреть значение res пробовали? Если там пусто, то вы можете хоть как угодно правильно присваивать - но проблема будет с тем, что парсится не так.

Comment: @A K да, только что понял, что проблема не в передаче, а в результате парсинга... Сейчас играюсь с селекторами отбора, т.к. передача в поле TextBoxContent корректная